# Is it possible to install postgresql 11 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-11

I'm running on a Ubuntu 14,04 ('trusty') with no possibility to upgrade (a complex website-management platform is dependant upon it), but I'd like to install the latest version of postgresql in parallel... are there any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried it just now, I followed the guide here: https://gist.github.com/alistairewj/8aaea0261fe4015333ddf8bed5fe91f8

```
# add postgresql to apt repository
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main'
# get the signing key and update
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
# install postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql-11

# ensure that the server is started by switching to the postgres user
sudo su - postgres
# I didn't do this part since the database was started during install
# and I checked via `psql`
# /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -l logfile start
```